# Deleting class file when program is running?

Tags: java, classpath, delete-file

One program of java is running and it has infinite loop. Now while program is running I delete the class file of that program so what will happen? Will program continue as it is or it will stop..?

Comment: What don't you try by yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dont worry, nothing happens. It is stored in JVM while running.

Comment: @ Rakesh Goswami : Please accept the answer, upvote if you choose.

Answer (score 3):

Once a Java class has loaded, it is not loaded again and can be deleted without impact.

You only get a problem if you delete the class before it has been loaded.